# Codeception: acceptance test with selenium fails on "textarea"

Tags: selenium, codeception

I've got a function:

```
public function waitAndFill($element, $value, $timeOut = null)
    {
        $I = $this;

        $I->_waitFor($element, $timeOut);
        $I->fillField($element, $value);
        $I->seeInField($element, $value);
    }
```

And I use it like this:
`$I->waitAndFill('#inputInfo', 'This is test info');`

The textarea looks as follows

```
<textarea id="inputInfo"
                      name="company_description"
                      ng-model="company.company_description"
                      class="form-control"></textarea>
```

So, my test fails with this:

```
 Step  I see in field "#inputInfo","This is test info"
 Fail  Failed testing for 'This is test info' in company_description's value: 
Failed asserting that an array contains 'This is test info'.
```

It works fine on `<input>` fields, but fails on `<textarea>`. Looks like it doesn't see any text at all.

This text is present on the screen shot made by the test.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug.  The problem is this:  `$I->seeInField($element, $value);` invokes `$this->proceedSeeInField(array $elements, $value);` which invokes a method `getText()` on the Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement object that it finds.  If you read the documentation for Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement#getText() method it says that it returns the innerText for that element.  So that's no bueno.  To workaround this I removed the conditional for the textarea in this function.

```
protected function proceedSeeInField(array $elements, $value)
    {
        $strField = reset($elements)->getAttribute('name');
        if (reset($elements)->getTagName() === 'select') {
            $el = reset($elements);
            $elements = $el->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath('.//option[@selected]'));
            if (empty($value) && empty($elements)) {
                return ['True', true];
            }
        }

        $currentValues = [];
        if (is_bool($value)) {
            $currentValues = [false];
        }
        foreach ($elements as $el) {
            if ($el->getTagName() === 'textarea') {
                $currentValues[] = $el->getText();
            } elseif ($el->getTagName() === 'input' && $el->getAttribute('type') === 'radio' || $el->getAttribute('type') === 'checkbox') {
                if ($el->getAttribute('checked')) {
                    if (is_bool($value)) {
                        $currentValues = [true];
                        break;
                    } else {
                        $currentValues[] = $el->getAttribute('value');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $currentValues[] = $el->getAttribute('value');
            }
        }

        return [
            'Contains',
            $value,
            $currentValues,
            "Failed testing for '$value' in $strField's value: " . implode(', ', $currentValues)
        ];
    }
```

You should change it to:

```
protected function proceedSeeInField(array $elements, $value)
    {
        $strField = reset($elements)->getAttribute('name');
        if (reset($elements)->getTagName() === 'select') {
            $el = reset($elements);
            $elements = $el->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath('.//option[@selected]'));
            if (empty($value) && empty($elements)) {
                return ['True', true];
            }
        }

        $currentValues = [];
        if (is_bool($value)) {
            $currentValues = [false];
        }
        foreach ($elements as $el) {
            if ($el->getTagName() === 'input' && $el->getAttribute('type') === 'radio' || $el->getAttribute('type') === 'checkbox') {
                if ($el->getAttribute('checked')) {
                    if (is_bool($value)) {
                        $currentValues = [true];
                        break;
                    } else {
                        $currentValues[] = $el->getAttribute('value');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $currentValues[] = $el->getAttribute('value');
            }
        }

        return [
            'Contains',
            $value,
            $currentValues,
            "Failed testing for '$value' in $strField's value: " . implode(', ', $currentValues)
        ];
    }
```

Now it calls getAttribute('value') just like any other input element.

The is in file WebDriver.php